# Pytest call setup() before fixture

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I am having difficulty using fixtures with my pytest unit tests.

I am using a test class like this:

```
class TestMyApp(object):

    def setup(self):
        self.client = mock_client()

    @pytest.fixture
    def client_item(self):
        return self.client.create_item('test_item')

    def test_something1(self, client_item):
        # Test here.
        pass
```

When I run the above test I get the following exception:

```
AttributeError: 'TestMyApp' object has no attribute 'client'
```

I believe this is because the `client_item()` fixture function is being called before the `setup()` function.

Am I using fixtures incorrectly? Or is there some way I can force `setup()` to be called before the fixture functions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixtures can use other fixtures, so you can use fixtures all the way down:

```
class TestMyApp(object):

    @pytest.fixture
    def client(self):
        return mock_client()

    @pytest.fixture
    def client_item(self, client):
        return client.create_item('test_item')

    def test_something1(self, client_item):
        # Test here.
        pass
```

The [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/xunit_setup.html) subtly recommends fixtures over xUnit style setup/teardown methods:

> While these setup/teardown methods are simple and familiar to those coming from a `unittest` or `nose` background, you may also consider using pytest’s more powerful [fixture mechanism](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#fixture) which leverages the concept of dependency injection, allowing for a more modular and more scalable approach for managing test state, especially for larger projects and for functional testing.

It goes on to say that the two styles *can* be mixed, but isn't clear about the order in which things will happen.